# jquery ajaxSubmit() not updating the master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have used jQuery form `ajaxSubmit()` function to post the the masterpage asynchronously.

What the scenario is I have master page in my application where the cart panel is there and 
inside it repeater is showing the items added into the cart by user.

To add a items into cart, a popup is there in content page so as soon as user click into add to cart button a popup will show the items added into cart but when I close the popup and goes to panel cart on master page it not showing data. So I decided to post back the master page on hover of mouse. So when I take my mouse cursor to cart panel it post back the page asynchronously and binding the repeater to from the List. Everything goes fine from server side but still not showing the repeater in client side.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my javascript function

```
 function setCart()     
        {   
            document.imgpicmycart.src = 'images/btn-mycart-orange-ovr.png'
            jQuery('#aspnetForm').ajaxSubmit();
        }
```

FYI, i have scriptmanager and update panel on my masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

You have totally mix up everything and that can not work.

The ajaxSubmit with together UpdatePanel, with asp.net - simple not work together -

The asp.net page contains some extra informations line the viewstate, the control validations, and other thinks that when you make a custom ajaxSubmit this can not work as you think, except if you are so expert and make a really good update to the replace content... how ever this is all ready made with the UpdatePanel.

So remove the ajaxSubmit and keep only the UpdatePanel to do your work and its going to work.

The ajaxSubmit plugin can work in other cases, with out UpdatePanel, with out control validations and viewstate, and under very specific input, output that you know exactly what you do and why.

(you can say that ajaxSubmit is for php, and UpdatePanel is for asp.net)